# I don't know how to use typedef enum

Tags: objective-c, typedef

```
typedef enum {
    kA = 0,
    kB,
    kC,
    kD,
    kE,
    kF
} index;

@interface myViewController : UITableViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    index enumIndex;
}
```

Hi, guys.

I declare index which is composed by typedef enum. But I didn't found code like that.
and If that code useful, does not need to release ?

I don't understand typedef enum in Objective C.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef enum` works exactly the same in Objective-C as it does in C.  There is no difference.

If I were to hazard a guess as to the compiler error that you didn't provide, I'd bet that `index` is already defined and it is complaining about redefinition.   In any case, make your typedef comprehensible, say `MyViewControllerIndex`.

Note also that your class names should start with capital letters; `MyViewController`.